# Ninject doesn't resolve dependencies for OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

```
public class WebAppHost {

    public WebAppHost(IAppSettings appSettings) {
        this._appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) {
        if(this._appSettings.StartApi)
            appBuilder.UseWebApi();
    }

}

public class AppContext {

    public static void Start(string[] args) {

        DynamicModule.Utility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModule.Utility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));

        _bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        WebApp.Start<WebAppHost>("uri");

    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel() {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    private static void ReigsterServices(IKernel kernel) {
        kernel.Bind<IAppSettings>().To<AppSettings>()
            .InRequestScope();
    }

}
```

When I try to access the resolved IAppSettings, it's always null and a null reference exception occurs. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWIN startup will create your `WebAppHost` instance for you without using your container. In order to perform the startup with a class that has been injected, use the following code:

```cs
public class AppContext {
    //[...]

    public static void Start(string[] args) {
        //[...]
        _bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);

        //Remember to dispose this or put around "using" construct.
        WebApp.Start("uri", builder =>
        {
            var webHost = _bootstrapper.Kernel.Get<WebAppHost>();
            webHost.Configuration(builder);
        } );
    }

    //[...]
}
```

This will call `Configuration` method in your `WebAppHost` instance with your `IAppSettings` injected.

PS: As a *suggestion*, I think you shouldn't use `InRequestScope()` for your `IAppSettings` binding in `RegisterServices`. Use singleton, transient or custom scope for that. From my experience you wouldn't need any application settings that are bound to a request scope.

Comment: This is a great way of solving my problem. Thank you!