# Access Ninject in Startup.cs

Tags: .net, oauth, ninject, owin

Is it possible to access ninject in startup.cs (Owin)?

I initialize OAuth in startup.cs and create a custom AuthenticationProvider.

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        [Inject]
        public IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider AuthorizationProvider { set; private get; }


        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/internal/token"),
                Provider = AuthorizationProvider,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            });

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
            });
        }
    }
```

Saldy ninject cannot inject the AuthorizationProvider because owin creates the startup instance. How do I inject depdendencies to OAuth authorization provider?

I instantiate ninject in "App_Start" -> NinjectWebCommon.cs like the scaffold created it.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace Qvg.Pflanzenlexikon.WebPortal
{
    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
...
```

Comment: This answer I gave is similar to your issue. Use that to perform injection of your `Startup.cs` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401900/ninject-doesnt-resolve-dependencies-for-owin/22409607#22409607

Comment: PS: To retrieve the kernel instance via the Ninject's bootstrapper anywhere: `(new Bootstrapper()).Kernel` - it is a singleton.